# How to resolve java.rmi.NotBoundException: rmi://localhost//HelloWorld?

Tags: java, rmi

Im starting to use Java RMI. Im tried to do an Hello World example but i didn't.
This is my remote interface code:

```
package server;

import java.rmi.Remote;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;

public interface Hello extends Remote
{
    public String saluta(String who) throws RemoteException;
}
```

This is my class that extends the remote interface:

```
package server;

import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject;

public class HelloWorld extends UnicastRemoteObject implements Hello
{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public HelloWorld() throws RemoteException
    {
        super();
    }

    public String saluta(String who) throws RemoteException
    {
        return "Hello " + who;
    }
}
```

This is my server:

```
package server;
import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;
import java.rmi.registry.Registry;
import java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Server
{

    static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("global");

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.setProperty("java.security.policy", "policy.all");
        if (System.getSecurityManager() == null)
        {
            System.setSecurityManager(new SecurityManager());
        }

        try
        {
            HelloWorld hello = new HelloWorld();

            Registry r = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(9000);


            logger.info("Creo l'oggetto");


            logger.info("...ora ne effettuo il rebind...");
            r.rebind("HelloWorld", hello);
            logger.info("...pronto");
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

And this is my client code:

```
package hello.client;
import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;
import java.rmi.registry.Registry;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Client
{
    static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("global");

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            Registry r = LocateRegistry.getRegistry(9000);
            logger.info("Sto cercando l'oggetto remoto...");
            Hello hello = (Hello) r.lookup("rmi://localhost//HelloWorld");


            System.out.println(hello.saluta("Graziano"));

        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

I created two separeted project,one for server and the other one for client as in image at following link:[image](http://www.mediafire.com/view/h5pvug5r2cqlamv/Immagine.png)
My server work perfectly, but the client get me this error:
java.rmi.NotBoundException: rmi://localhost//HelloWorld on line 18

what's wrong?? If someone can, please post me an example! Thanks :D

P.S: Maybe could be important! This is the external configuration tool:
[image2](http://www.mediafire.com/view/qzoipupq74870cu/Immagine2.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of the lookup URL. Lookup URLs are for the `Naming` class. You already have a Registry object and it was created for a speficic host and port. *Ergo* you only need the lookup name, same as when you bound. Just use `"HelloWorld"`.

Comment: thanks i used that string but the error don't go away :(